# Как сгенерировать 25 фотокарточек на основе данных объекта?

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты

Есть 25 фотокарточек. У каждой есть адрес изображения, число лайков, комментарий и описание. Эти параметры записаны в объект. Далее создаётся шаблон фотокарточки на основе этого объекта.

Итак, вопрос - как сгенерировать 25 фотокарточек с разными данными?
Можно ли проитерировать поле url, но как тогда это сделать?
Пожалуйста, помогите, чем сможете.

```
//чертёж фотокарточки
var photoCards = {
    url: 'photos/[i].jpg',
    likes: getRandomInt(15, 200),
    comments: arrayRandElement(commentsArray),
    description: arrayRandElement(descriptionArray)
};

//создание шаблона фотокарточки
function CreatePhotoTemplate(phtCard) {
    var picture_template = document.querySelector('#picture-template').content;
    var card = picture_template.cloneNode(true);

    card.querySelector('img').src = phtCard.url;
    card.querySelector('.picture-likes').textContent = phtCard.likes;
    card.querySelector('.picture-comments').textContent = phtCard.comments;

    return card;
};

for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    ???
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое?

```js
let array = (new Array(25)).fill(undefined).map(
  (_,index)=> ({
            url: `photos/${index}.jpg`,
            likes: (Math.random() * (200 - 15) + 15)|0,
            comments: "random Comment",
            description: "random Description"
        }
      )
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Можно же просто `=> ({ ... }));` :)

Comment: @entithat подправил спс.

Comment: `|0 + 15` - это баг.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему это баг? Я всего лишь округлил

Comment: Потому что приоритет операций проверь.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так лучше навернека?

Comment: Да, лучше. Впрочем я бы сначала добавил 15, а потом делал `|0` - тогда бы скобки не понадобились.

Comment: @Qwertiy совершенству нет предела. Спс